# determine the radical $\sqrt{m\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, radicals

Task: determine the radical $\sqrt{m\mathbb{Z}}$.

Obviously $m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \sqrt{m\mathbb{Z}}$.

But how to systematically determine the elements of $\sqrt{m\mathbb{Z}}$?

I guess it has something to do with prime factors to a power greater than one in the prime factorization of $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just follow the definition. For $k\in \mathbb Z$ we have $k \in \sqrt{(m)}$, if for some $N \ge 0$, $k^N \in (m)$, that is $m\mid k^N$. Now let $m = \prod_p p^{\nu_p(n)}$ be the prime decomposition of $m$ and $k = \prod_p p^{n_p(k)}$ that of $k$. $m \mid k^N$ now reads $N\nu_p(k) \ge \nu_p(n)$ for all primes $p$. This is trivially true for the primes with $\nu_p(n) = 0$, and can be fulfilled for all $p$ iff $\nu_p(k) > 0$ for all $p$ with $\nu_p(n)>0$. That is we have $k \in \sqrt{(m)}$ iff $k$ is divided by each prime factor of $m$, so $\sqrt{(m)}$ is generated by $k := \prod_{\nu_p(n) > 0} p$.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm wrong -- should it be:

"This is trivially true for the primes with $ν_p(n)=0$, and can be fulfilled for all p iff $ν_p(k)>ν_p(n)$ for all $p$ with $ν_p(n)>0$."

Comment: No if $\nu_p(k) > 0$ for all $p$ with $\nu_p(n) > 0$, we can just choose $N$ "big enough", for example $N = \max_p \nu_p(n)$. Then $N\nu_p(k) \ge \nu_p(n)$ for all $p$ with $\nu_p(k) > 0$.

Comment: True. I think the cases $\nu_p(n) = 0$ and $\nu_p(n) \neq 0$ are mixed up, though -- meaning, the second case is again $\nu_p(n) = 0$ but should be $\nu_p(n) \neq 0$, I guess..

Comment: @aenvaPove9 Thx, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the characterization of $\sqrt{I}$ as being the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$? If not, it would make a great exercise for you to prove :)

Since you know that $(m)\subseteq(p)$ iff $p$ divides $m$, you have a complete list of prime ideals containing $(m)$. Then their intersection is just $(\prod_{p|m}p)$.